# Why for loop update all indexes nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to work on nested arrays for space battle program.
For fleet fighting i write this:

```
//Roll a dice function
const randomNumber = (number) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * number);
}


//Here we declare ships stats
// - 0 : Health
// - 1 : Damages
// - 2 : Chances to hit
// - 3 : Chances to be hit
//  - 4 (add by decideTargets function (line 100)) : Position of the target in enemy fleet

const vaisseaux = {
    frigate : [500, 200, 90, 50],
    heavyFrigate : [750, 300, 80, 25],
    cruiser : [1500, 500, 75, 15],
    attackCruiser : [750, 750, 80, 15],
    battleship : [3000, 1000, 70, 10]
}

/**
* Here we declare the composition of the fleet
*  - 0 : Friates
*  - 1 : Heavy Frigates
*  - 2 : Cruisers
*  - 3 : Attack Cruisers
*  - 4 : Battleships
*/
const fleet1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
const fleet2 = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10];

function fleetConstructor(fleet) {
    /**
     * Here, we build an array of ships in fleets.
     * It'll be a 2 dimentions array
     * ___________________________________________________________
     * |Frigates | HFrigates | Cruisers  | ACruisers  | BShip     |
     * |---------|-----------|-----------|------------|-----------|
     * |stats F1 | stats HF1 | stats C1  | stats AC1  | stats BS1 |
     * |stats F2 | stats HF2 | stats C2  | stats AC2  | stats BS2 |
     * |etc ...  | etc ...   | etc ...   | etc ...    | etc ...   |
     * 
     */
    
    const finalFleetArray = [[], [], [], [], []];

    for (let f = 0; f < fleet[0]; f++) {
        finalFleetArray[0].push(vaisseaux.frigate);
    }

    for (let f = 0; f < fleet[0]; f++) {
        finalFleetArray[1].push(vaisseaux.heavyFrigate);
    }

    for (let f = 0; f < fleet[0]; f++) {
        finalFleetArray[2].push(vaisseaux.cruiser);
    }

    for (let f = 0; f < fleet[0]; f++) {
        finalFleetArray[3].push(vaisseaux.attackCruiser);
    }

    for (let f = 0; f < fleet[0]; f++) {
        finalFleetArray[4].push(vaisseaux.battleship);
    }

    return finalFleetArray;
}

function decideTargets(firstFleet, secondFleet) {
    /**
     * Here we need to find distint target to every ships in fleets
     * Return fleet array
     */

    // i go throught ship types
    for(let i = 0; i < firstFleet.length; i++) {

        // j go throught each ship
        for (let j = 0; j < firstFleet[i].length; j++) {

            firstFleet[i][j].push([
                randomNumber(secondFleet.length - 1), 
                randomNumber(secondFleet[i].length - 1)
            ]);

        }
        
        console.log(firstFleet[i]);
    }
    return firstFleet;
}


/**
 * DEBUG
 */

//Building fleets
const attackerFleet = fleetConstructor(fleet1);
const defenderFleet = fleetConstructor(fleet2);


//Acquire targets
const finalCountdown = decideTargets(attackerFleet, defenderFleet);
```

My problem is that decideTargets function have the objective of finding unique random array each time. But the log display that :

```
[
  [ 500, 200, 90, 50, [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 7 ], [ 1, 0 ] ],
  [ 500, 200, 90, 50, [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 7 ], [ 1, 0 ] ],
  [ 500, 200, 90, 50, [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 7 ], [ 1, 0 ] ]
]
[
  [ 750, 300, 80, 25, [ 1, 6 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 2, 4 ] ],
  [ 750, 300, 80, 25, [ 1, 6 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 2, 4 ] ],
  [ 750, 300, 80, 25, [ 1, 6 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 2, 4 ] ]
]
[
  [ 1500, 500, 75, 15, [ 3, 8 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 0, 8 ] ],
  [ 1500, 500, 75, 15, [ 3, 8 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 0, 8 ] ],
  [ 1500, 500, 75, 15, [ 3, 8 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 0, 8 ] ]
]
[
  [ 750, 750, 80, 15, [ 0, 0 ], [ 2, 6 ], [ 0, 7 ] ],
  [ 750, 750, 80, 15, [ 0, 0 ], [ 2, 6 ], [ 0, 7 ] ],
  [ 750, 750, 80, 15, [ 0, 0 ], [ 2, 6 ], [ 0, 7 ] ]
]
[
  [ 3000, 1000, 70, 10, [ 1, 4 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 1, 4 ] ],
  [ 3000, 1000, 70, 10, [ 1, 4 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 1, 4 ] ],
  [ 3000, 1000, 70, 10, [ 1, 4 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 1, 4 ] ]
]
```

Each time the second for iterate, it push the random array for all j values.

I try to change the loops by while loops, change the second for loop by foreach. I also tried to separate the arrayArgument.push statement in an other function (and the double for loop call it)
I get the same result each time.

The array i want is :

```
[
  [ 500, 200, 90, 50, [ 3, 4 ] ],
  [ 500, 200, 90, 50, [ 2, 7 ] ],
  [ 500, 200, 90, 50, [ 1, 0 ] ]
]
[
  [ 750, 300, 80, 25, [ 1, 6 ] ],
  [ 750, 300, 80, 25, [ 2, 3 ] ],
  [ 750, 300, 80, 25, [ 2, 4 ] ]
]
[
  [ 1500, 500, 75, 15, [ 3, 8 ] ],
  [ 1500, 500, 75, 15, [ 4, 5 ] ],
  [ 1500, 500, 75, 15, [ 0, 8 ] ]
]
[
  [ 750, 750, 80, 15, [ 0, 0 ] ],
  [ 750, 750, 80, 15, [ 2, 6 ] ],
  [ 750, 750, 80, 15, [ 0, 7 ] ]
]
[
  [ 3000, 1000, 70, 10, [ 1, 4 ] ],
  [ 3000, 1000, 70, 10, [ 3, 8 ] ],
  [ 3000, 1000, 70, 10, [ 1, 4 ] ]
]
```

EDIT (The answer) : in fleetConstructor() i create array with basically this line : array1 = array2.
In Javascript, this mean that changes to array1 affect also array2.
so i have to transform each for statement in :

```
    for (let f = 0; f < fleet[0]; f++) {
        finalFleetArray[0][f] = vaisseaux.frigate.slice();
    }
```

This solve the problem as slice, create new array instead of just copy it.

Comment: You probably want `push(randomNumber(10), randomNumber(10))` rather than `push([randomNumber(10), randomNumber(10)])`? Please show what output you're hoping to generate, not just the output you're getting. That said, pushing values into an array, in a place that your iterator hasn't reach yet, is almost guaranteed to yield bugs because adding new data invalidates what the loop counter would have pointed to before you did that.

Comment: Ideally i want tu keep the two numbers in an array.
i edit for what i want ! thank you

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question: I've turned your code into a runnable snippet, and it already generates the output you want given the input array you're showing?

Comment: I'm very confused that you are right. 
Simplyfy my code with other variable name than the original. 
still not work in original code. 
You think i can link the .js file here ?

Comment: Take your original code that isn't working, and reduce it to [mcve] form. Then [edit] your post to put _that_ code in, with just enough code to call it with some input and show the output.

Comment: Just update my post. I'm so sorry i didn't test my question code before.

Comment: Note that you both turned this back into non-runnable code, and you've also left a bunch of things in that can be hardcoded. The [mcve] article is quite helpful in teaching you how to turn your code into its minimal form, which in this case means having two variables that contain the finished input that you're calling  `decideTargets` with, as well as logging the result of _calling_ that function. And make sure that's a runnable snippet again as this is plain JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend mutating the original 3D matrix.

Instead, you can map each plane, row, column to a new copy with modified columns.

**Note:** I modified the `randomNumber` function to take a `min` and a `max`.

```js
const originalMatrix3d = [
  [[1,  2,  3,  4] , [1,  2,  3,  4] , [1,  2,  3,  4]],
  [[5,  6,  7,  8] , [5,  6,  7,  8] , [5,  6,  7,  8]],
  [[9, 10, 11, 12] , [9, 10, 11, 12] , [9, 10, 11, 12]]
];

const updatedMatrix3d = decideTargets(originalMatrix3d);

console.log(updatedMatrix3d.map(JSON.stringify));

function decideTargets(matrix3d) {
  return matrix3d.map(function(plane) {
    return plane.map(function(row) {
      return [...row, [randomNumber(1, 20), randomNumber(1, 20)]]
    });
  })
}

// Roll a dice function
function randomNumber(min, max) {
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('You must supply a value');
  }
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I don't understand what [... row] do.

Comment: I am spreading the `row` (array of cols) into a new "row" array, and adding an additional tuple (pair of random ints) of random rolls to it.

Comment: Thank you, you can see my whole code now (the original question was wrongly asked) but you are the one who give me the idea of the answer.